Identify starting row of actual data in Pandas DataFrame with merged header cells
My original df looks like this -
df
Note in the data frame:

The headers are there till row 3 & from row 4 onwards, the values for those headers are starting.
The numbers of rows & columns merged to create the headers are not same
The values (from row 4 onwards) can contain missing values.

In Jupyter Notebook, I get something like this -
pandas_df

The requirement: Identify row number i.e., the row from where the values for the headers are starting and from df to df, this row number can vary (i.e., header may include more/less number of rows.

One can use this code to generate the given table -
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1': ['Column1', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 11.0, 32.0, 22.0],
 'Col2': ['Column2', np.nan, 'Col2PartA', 'P', 'A', 'M', 'C'],
 'Col3': [np.nan, np.nan, 'Col2PartB', 'PP', 'HJ', 'KL', 'IO'],
 'Col4': ['Column3', 'Col3PartA', np.nan, 10, np.nan, 24, 43],
 'Col5': [np.nan, 'Col3PartB', np.nan, 23, np.nan, 21, 56],
 'Col6': ['Column4', 'Col4PartA', 'Col4PartA_pt1', 'KLJ', 'TYI', 'MOP', np.nan],
 'Col7': [np.nan, np.nan, 'Col4PartA_pt2', 'WER', 'FYI', 'NOI', np.nan],
 'Col8': [np.nan, 'Col4PartB', 'Col4PartB_pt1', 'DFG', np.nan, 'UIT', np.nan]}

pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I am expecting some solution around NLP, but if there are any simple logic that would also be a great help.

Code
# find index of last row where any column contains 'Col'
n = pandas_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Col')).any(axis=1).cumsum().idxmax()

# extract and transpose header rows up to index n (variable header)
header = pandas_df.loc[:n].T.copy()

# forward fill the first column
header[0] = header[0].ffill()

# forward fill each column group-wise and then row-wise up to index n
for i in range(n):
    header[i + 1] = header.groupby(list(range(i + 1)))[i + 1].ffill()
    header[i + 1] = header.loc[:, :i + 1].ffill(axis=1)[i + 1]

# create a multiIndex from variable header
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(header, names=[None] * (n + 1))

# pandas_df without header and set multiIndex by variable cols
out = pandas_df.loc[n + 1:].set_axis(cols, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

out:


intermediate
variable cols(multi-index of header)
cols:
MultiIndex([('Column1',   'Column1',       'Column1'),
            ('Column2',   'Column2',     'Col2PartA'),
            ('Column2',   'Column2',     'Col2PartB'),
            ('Column3', 'Col3PartA',     'Col3PartA'),
            ('Column3', 'Col3PartB',     'Col3PartB'),
            ('Column4', 'Col4PartA', 'Col4PartA_pt1'),
            ('Column4', 'Col4PartA', 'Col4PartA_pt2'),
            ('Column4', 'Col4PartB', 'Col4PartB_pt1')],
           )


IIUC, you can identify columns header values bases on the substring 'Col':
pandas_df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('Col')).any(1)

Output:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool


Yeah... What @PandaKim did.
